# Plotting chronological sorted data from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am having difficulties in understanding the right order on how to plot in a chronological order some values.

I have my dataset

```
Date                User         Bool_Value
2020/02/12        3168           True
2020/02/12        3121           False
2020/02/14        421            False
2020/02/18        512            True
2020/02/18        5241           True
2020/02/18        314            False
```

and so on.

I would like to plot only users having a boolean value `= True` sorted by date. 
The first thing that I did was filtering by `Bool_Value`, then grouping these values by `Date`:

```
df_1=df[df['Bool_Value']==True].groupby('Date')
```

Now I should use matplotlib to plot these value, showing users and date, as I already filtered users by boolean values. 
Could you please explain me how to do it?

Comment: Do you want to plot only one value per date? or more than one is fine? (like for the 18/02)

Comment: @DavideBrex, I would like to plot all the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = []
df.append(['2020/02/12',3168,True])
df.append(['2020/02/12',3121,False])
df.append(['2020/02/14',421,False])
df.append(['2020/02/18',512,True])
df.append(['2020/02/18',5241,True])
df.append(['2020/02/18',314,False])

for entry in df:
    date = entry[0]
    value = entry[1]
    bool = entry[2]
    if(bool):
        plt.scatter(date, value, color='k', s=100)

plt.show()
```

output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your data table it is not clear, what the actual data type of the `Date` column is, so it might require conversion. Then, pandas data frames come with simple plotting methods.

```
# convert date column to proper datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# get only entries with Bool_Value (== True is not necessary, see Boolean indexing)
sub = df[df['Bool_Value']]

# pandas data frames have a plotting method
sub.plot('Date', 'User', marker='o', ls='')
```

[image]